# Open File Dialog, One Filter for Multiple Excel Extensions?

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I want to use an OpenFileDialog object to browse to an excel file. I would like to set the filter to open files with different types of excel extensions like: .xls, .xlsm, .xlsx and so on.

what I am using is this:

```
OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
of.Filter = "Excel Files(.xls)|*.xls| 
    Excel Files(.xlsx)|*.xlsx| Excel Files(*.xlsm)|*.xlsm";
```

This works, but the user must select the correct excel file type from the dropdown in the OpenFileDialog.

How can one apply a filter for all types of Excel extensions?

Something like: "...Excel Files (.xls, .xlsx, .xlxm)|*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm;"

Comment: The MSDN documentation has all the details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx

Comment: Thanks David and odyodyodys. Yes the example there on the page and I did read the page, but somehow I somehow missed the section. Thanks.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Use a semicolon

```
OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
of.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
```

Comment: Awesome! Needed it for audio files `dialog.Filter = "Audio Files|*.mp3;*.wav;*.wmp";`

Comment: Thanks! Saved me some time searching on net

Comment: For two filters - in my case  CSV and Excel files - I used : `CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm`

Comment: ```Excel Files|*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.xlsb;*.xltx;*.xltm;*.xls;*.xlt;*.xls;*.xml;*.xml;*.xlam;*.xla;*.xlw;*.xlr;```

extensions from: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/File-formats-that-are-supported-in-Excel-0943ff2c-6014-4e8d-aaea-b83d51d46247

Comment: you can use a * to refer more than one type, example: `of.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls*";`

Answer (score 9):

If you want to merge the filters (eg. CSV and Excel files), use this formula:

```
OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
of.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx";
```

Or if you want to see XML or PDF files in one time use this:

```
of.Filter = @" XML or PDF |*.xml;*.pdf";
```